# Is there any way to access currently processed value without promises or classes while it is being modified inside methods chain?

Tags: javascript, date, methods, chaining, method-chaining

I've got this code:

```js
var a = new Date();
var b = a.toISOString();
var c = b.slice(0, b.indexOf('.'));
var d = c.replace('T', ' ');

console.log('a:', a, '\nb:', b, '\nc:', c, '\nd:', d);
```

What I'd like to achieve, is all four lines combine into one, without using callbacks, classes or promises, just pure methods chaining.
Just like this i.e.: `new Date().toISOString().slice(0, *reference to ISO stringified date*.indexOf('.')).replace('T', ' ');`

But the problem is, there's no way that `this` keyword could point to/return value before `.slice()` method and after `.toISOString()` one.
Or maybe it could, using some advanced techniques, but I don't know about them.

So is there any way to achieve what I want without using callbacks/promises?
I'm asking for my personal purposes, as a matter of curiosity.

Comment: I don't see any callback or promise, can you make the question clear? Do you want to chain all the calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible.

However, there is an ECMAScript proposal called [pipeline operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator) which tries to solve this problem. The exact syntax is currently unsettled and the feature might not make it into the language at all.

Your example could look like this (again, this is just a proposal and does not actually work):

```
var res = new Date().toISOString() |> (_ => _.slice(0, _.indexOf('.')).replace('T', ' '));
```

This hardly improves readability, though.

Comment: So looks like only callbacks and promises are only way, when want to chain methods and keep track of modified value. Thanks anyway!

Comment: No not really. This has nothing to do with callbacks or promises but rather the returned value and the way you use it. If you were not using `b.indexOf('.')` as a parameter, you would be able to chain the calls.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do it now using [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) introduced in ECMAScript 2015, though it may not have entirely the features you want.

If you want to get access to more intermediate results, the syntax might look pretty messy.

```js
var y = ((d = new Date().toISOString()) => d.slice(0, d.indexOf('.')).replace('T',' '))(); 

console.log(y);
```

In this particular case a UTC timestamp is being represented as local so not a good idea in that context.